# How to assign multiple values to single index in array in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

```html
$def_field = array(
 "def_value" => 'Display Name',
 "def_value" => 'Database Value'
);
```

Here i have a array in that i need to assign both Display Name and Database Value to def_value key. how to do that can anyone please  help me..

Comment: How does your output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is incorrect as the second index will override the first index value because they have the same name. So You will have only this in your array:

```
$def_field = array(
    "def_value" => 'Database Value'
);
```

You can do it these ways

```
$def_field = array(
  "def_value" => array('Display Name','Database Value')
);
```

Or like this:

```
$def_field = [];
$def_field['def_value'][] = 'Display Name';
$def_field['def_value'][] = 'Database Value';
```

The second exemple kind of explains everything. You will create an array with index `$def_value` inside `array $def_field` with values `'Display Name'` having `index 0` and `'Database Value'` having `index 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to add it as a nested array like this:

```
$def_field = array(
    "def_value" => array('Display Name','Database Value')
);
```